# REST API script taking longer time to execute

Tags: rest, automation

I am new to API automation. When trying to execute the basic script in selenium I am getting the below error. Can some one please help me with it.

```
package GetRequest;

import static io.restassured.RestAssured.given;  
import io.restassured.RestAssured;

public class trying {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        // base url
        RestAssured.baseURI="https://maps.googleapis.com";
        given().
            param("location","-33.8670522,151.1957362").
            param("radius","1500").
            param("Key","AIzaSyBBuJ-3wBy1VKGUMtNqO8PpAHWGESIItAo").
            when().
            get("/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json").
            then().
            assertThat().statusCode(200);
    }
}
```

Comment: Code :
package GetRequest;

import static io.restassured.RestAssured.given;

import io.restassured.RestAssured;

public class trying {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  // base url
  RestAssured.baseURI="https://maps.googleapis.com";
  given().
  param("location","-33.8670522,151.1957362").
  param("radius","1500").
  param("Key","AIzaSyBBuJ-3wBy1VKGUMtNqO8PpAHWGESIItAo").
  when().
  get("/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json").
  then().
  assertThat().statusCode(200);

 }

}

Comment: ERROR MESSAGE 

   error message 

Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
 at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
 at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
 at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
 at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
 at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
 at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow! Instead of posting comments in your own question, you can edit your question. That makes your question more readable.

Answer (score 0):

What is the port you are connecting at ? Have you specified that somewhere ? Are you using proxy ?

Why not try something like?

```
@BeforeClass
public void setProxy() 
{
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", YOUR_PROXY_HOST_HERE);
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", YOUR_PROXY_PORT_HERE);
}
```

Comment: Hi, i have not used any proxy and this is the issue for all the simple api when trying to execute the script from selenium. The same api executes properly in both postman and  in the browser. Also these api doesn't required to be connected to any port.